# Retriveing logs from "Developer script exception"

Tags: logging

When a `Developer script exception` email is generated, is there any way to view\capture the debug log as well?

Comment: Not unless you had a trace previously set up for the user that caused the exception

Comment: This is also a feature that I believe we are going to have more specific control over in the Summer '17 release.

Comment: @Eric ya that's what I figured.. I was hoping there might be some special exception around these that I was unaware of.

Comment: @JeffBennett any sources?  I'm trying to help an on-call team get better visibility into salesforce

Comment: @NSjonas, Funnily enough, yes.  My source is that I created a ticket with Salesforce in February for this same feature.  Not being able to control visibility of debug logs represents a security issue for companies who do not want their Contact and Account data e-mailed in the clear.  The response was that R&D has tentatively scheduled a fix for the Summer '17 release.  While they have not been clear about what the "fix" will be, I am assuming it is some sort of setting that controls when debug logs are sent with exception e-mails.